# Set theory. Let A be a set. Then A⊆P(∪A).

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A be a set. Then A⊆P(∪A).

I already tried to do this question and lost points. can someone please show me how to correctly solve this problem so I can be prepared for the midterm.

[image]

Comment: You need provide *context*: level, what you already know, what are the things you can use, etc. Perhaps including your previous attempt so we can tell where you went wrong would also help.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin I've added a picture of how I tried to solve the problem.

Comment: $A$ is not a subset of $P(A)$ in general; that’s where your error lies.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the definitions carefully. You need to show that if $a\in A$, then $a\in\wp\left(\bigcup A\right)$, i.e., $a\subseteq\bigcup A$. To do this, you need to show that if $a\in A$, and $x\in a$, then $x\in\bigcup A$. What is the definition of $\bigcup A$? Something is an element of $\bigcup A$ if and only if … what?

Your attempt contains several errors. First, it’s not generally true that $A=\bigcup A$. If $A=\{\varnothing\}$, for instance, then $A\ne\varnothing$, but $\bigcup A=\varnothing$ (why?). Thus, you cannot conclude that $\wp(A)=\wp\left(\bigcup A\right)$. Finally, $A$ is always an **element** of $\wp(A)$, but it is not in general a **subset** of $\wp(A)$: that happens only when every element of $A$ is also a subset of $A$, which is by no means always the case.